# Speakers and headphones have different independent volume levels

Tags: linux-mint, audio, alsa, alsamixer

Linux Mint 18.2 MATE.

I tried to increase the volume in headphones via `alsamixer`, but thereafter I have different volume levels for speakers and headphones. How can I make the only one level for everything (or make headphones sounds a bit louder, but anyway it has to relate to speakers' Master level)?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I suggest using `pavucontrol` for more detailed Pulse Audio controls. alsa-mixer is just not enough these days I'm afraid.

With `pavucontrol` you can individually modify applications and hardware volumes etc.

Beyond that have a look at the arch wiki, you can link the volumes with a script by using the `pactl` backend.

I'm not exactly sure how but I bet you can find some inspiration here:  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples